# Hudson email extension fails with "No authentication mechansims supported by both server and client"

Tags: email, hudson

After upgrading Hudson from 2 to 3 and running it in Tomcat its email extension no longer sends emails and fails with the error (even with a typo in the word "mechansims":))

```
ERROR: No authentication mechansims supported by both server and client
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: No authentication mechansims supported by both server and client
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:756)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:669)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.send(Mailer.java:505)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.send(Mailer.java:476)
    at hudson.tasks.MailSender.execute(MailSender.java:91)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer.perform(Mailer.java:112)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:34)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:646)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:624)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:600)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:566)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1414)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:40)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:81)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:137)
```

Is it a bug of the plugin, or maybe someone knows where the problem might be? I tried adding SMTP Authentication credentials in the main Hudson configuration page removing it - it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this could be a bug in Hudson 3 core. It might be related to http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/356988/. Could you downgrade the javax.mail jar in the hudson.war from 1.4.4 to 1.4 to see if that resolves the issue?

Thanks,
Steve.

Answer (score 0):

See if it doesn't have to do with TLS encryption, modify the java arguments that start Hudson to include: -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true